# Exchange subfolders notification with Windows 10 Phone?

Tags: notifications, outlook, exchange

I was finally pushed off my Blackberry Q10 by my company. I moved to a Nokia 640XL with Windows 8.1 which does not support notifications for sub-folders in Outlook/Exchange. See: [Enable sound notifications for email subfolders](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/6146/enable-sound-notifications-for-email-subfolders)

Is this corrected in Windows 10 Phone's email app?

So far I haven't found any article that goes into the email app in nearly enough depth to determine this.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish seeing sub-folder notifications with Windows 10 Mobile with some outlook rule tricks. One way is by simply editing the outlook rule used to move the email to a sub-folder. The option you want is "display a Desktop Alert." While this does make the rule client-only and thus only works when Outlook is running, it is a workaround.

Unfortunately, you can't just create a rule for notifications. The reason this works is because it stops the email from being sorted server side in Exchange and so for a brief moment, until your desktop outlook application sorts it, it shows up in the inbox.

Also, if you have Clutter, Junk, etc in OWA turned on and the email goes in there, you won't get notified on your mobile phone, except by manually looking in that folder and syncing it.

I'll agree, this is a pretty weird (If not horrible) workaround and I don't like it. But it's the only way I've found around this issue until Microsoft fixes it, if they do.

Special thanks to reedmich on the thread for the initial tip...
http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-8-1-preview-developers/276981-alerts-email-subfolders.html

Answer (score 1):

I called MS support. Unfortunately this is not featured in Windows 10 and most likely will not be. Very sad. This leaves BB as only option.